# iReport: how to hard fix a detail band's height, independent of it's content

Tags: jasper-reports, height, ireport

I use iReport and I try to fix a detail band's height independently of its content. My problem is that if one of my text fields has more than one line, the band *"grows"* and because of this I get a second page.

So is there any possibility to hard fix the height of a detail band?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the stretch type for the text field to "No Stretch" and the split type (see the properties menu) for the detail band to "Prevent".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tried it. I found another solution.

Comment: @Florian: Do share the solution. You can add your answer in the Your Answer part and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Since we could not find any direct options, We are doing this in an indirect method, having PLSQL Procedure for data fetching, different sub-datasets are used for filling fixed height detail areas, so each fixed datasets are filled with max.rows which it can accomodate (within sub procedures). Hope it helps someone.